# Matlab operators meaning

Tags: matlab, operators

What is the use of the operator .^ in matlab?

I wanted to know what could be the meaning of such an operator, for eg, in the system of equatios as shown below - 
x1dot = -x1 - 2 *x2 .*x1**.^**2+x2

Comment: It may be interesting to have a look at the [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) manual.

Answer (score 1):

Any operator preceded by a `.` in MATLAB indicates that it will operate element-wise. In the case of `.^`, it is the [element-wise power](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) operator.

This means that it will raise each element in one array to the corresponding power specified in another array.

```
[1, 2, 3] .^ [1, 2, 3]
% [1, 4, 27]
```